# DateTime conversion fails only in MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am running a procedure that transforms some data in a staging table and then merges it into the fact table. 2 of the columns are varchar as the data provider formats the datetime fields on export as English readable (20/09/2023 16:48:00). During the procedure run the system returns the error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'. I am not sure why this is happening as when I check the seed table after the fail, all values are either NULL or correctly formatted. I can also run a SELECT query where I perform the same conversion and the results displays fine without any conversion errors, so I have to assume the issue is in my PROC.

This is the staging table Schema

```
[staging].[SeedStoredLocalBags](
    [LocCode] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [SessionID] [varchar](22) NULL,
    [TimeStored] [varchar](55) NULL,
    [TimeRemoved] [varchar](55) NULL,
    [StoredBy] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [RemovedBy] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [RemovalMethod] [tinyint] NULL,
    [RemovalMethodDesc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AnalystRef] [int] NULL
```

This is the Fact schema

```
[pmr].[StoredLocalBag](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationId] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Session] [nvarchar](22) NULL,
    [TimeStored] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [TimeRemoved] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [StoredBy] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [RemovedBy] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [RemovalMethod] [tinyint] NULL,
    [DeletedAt] [datetime2](0) NULL
```

This is the procedure (I've removed what I feel isn't relevant but kept the format conversion.

```
PROCEDURE [staging].[StoredLocalBagsProc]
    @AnalystRef int
    AS       
        BEGIN
           SET NOCOUNT ON;            
          DECLARE @BranchNumber varchar(4)
            SELECT @BranchNumber = CAST(Branch AS varchar(4)) FROM pmr.AnalystLicense WHERE PSLAccountCode = @AnalystRef
            BEGIN
            UPDATE staging.StoredLocalBags
            SET LocCode = @BranchNumber + '-' + LocCode
            WHERE AnalystRef = @AnalystRef;
            UPDATE staging.StoredLocalBags
            SET TimeStored = NULL
            WHERE AnalystRef = @AnalystRef AND TimeStored = '';
            UPDATE staging.StoredLocalBags
            SET [TimeStored] = SUBSTRING([TimeStored],7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING([TimeStored],4,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING([TimeStored],1,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING([TimeStored],12,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING([TimeStored],15,2) + ':'  + SUBSTRING([TimeStored],18,2)
            WHERE AnalystRef = @AnalystRef AND [TimeStored] IS NOT NULL; 
            UPDATE staging.StoredLocalBags
            SET TimeRemoved = NULL
            WHERE AnalystRef = @AnalystRef AND TimeRemoved = '';
            UPDATE staging.StoredLocalBags
            SET [TimeRemoved] = SUBSTRING([TimeRemoved],7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING([TimeRemoved],4,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING([TimeRemoved],1,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING([TimeRemoved],12,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING([TimeRemoved],15,2) + ':'  + SUBSTRING([TimeRemoved],18,2)
            WHERE AnalystRef = @AnalystRef AND [TimeRemoved] IS NOT NULL;             
            END
          MERGE pmr.StoredLocalBag AS tgt
          USING staging.StoredLocalBags as src
          ON (tgt.LocationId = src.LocCode AND tgt.Session = src.SessionID AND tgt.TimeStored = src.TimeStored)
          WHEN MATCHED AND src.AnalystRef = @AnalystRef THEN 
              UPDATE SET                            
            TimeStored = src.[TimeStored],
            TimeRemoved = src.[TimeRemoved],
            StoredBy = src.StoredBy,
            RemovedBy = src.RemovedBy,
            RemovalMethod = src.[RemovalMethod]
              WHEN NOT MATCHED AND src.AnalystRef = @AnalystRef THEN
                  INSERT ([LocationId],[Session],[TimeStored],[TimeRemoved],[StoredBy],[RemovedBy],[RemovalMethod],[DeletedAt])
                  VALUES (
                      src.LocCode,                      
                      src.[SessionID],
                      src.[TimeStored],
                      src.[TimeRemoved],
                      src.StoredBy,
                      src.RemovedBy,
                      src.[RemovalMethod],
                      NULL
                  );                         
        END;
```

The 2 Date Columns would look like this before.

| TimeStored | TimeRemoved |
| --- | --- |
| 19/09/2023 16:50:00 | 20/09/2023 12:05:00 |
| 19/09/2023 17:25:00 | NULL |
| 15/09/2023 09:15:00 | 18/09/2023 14:30:00 |

And after the conversion, once the error shows, if I check the table it would show

| TimeStored | TimeRemoved |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-19 16:50:00 | 2023-09-20 12:05:00 |
| 2023-09-19 17:25:00 | NULL |
| 2023-09-15 09:15:00 | 2023-09-18 14:30:00 |

So as you can see the conversion is fine for all non-NULL values. Not sure if it is relevant but just to add, I have no control over how the staging data is delivered, I have to take it as it is currently and transform on my server.

Comment: Instead of messing around with string stuff, why not just use a style for the conversion `CONVERT(datetime, TimeRemoved, 103)` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles

Comment: You should move the src.AnalystRef = @AnalystRef thing to the merge join. Also, what's with the random BEGIN / END in the middle of nowhere. Finally, it's hard to guess but it might upconverts rows ahead of time so your other rows which aren't part of same analystRef are still being converted. Or the date format you use are bad, because it depends on the system settings. `set dateformat 'dmy'
select cast('2023-09-19 16:50:00' as datetime)`

Comment: Conversion can fail for *any* number of reasons and not just in MERGE. They'll fail for the same reason in WHERE or JOIN, or anything that tries to compare an unknown string to a date using the server's localization settings. Use the *correct* type instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be solved by a combination of 2 of the comments above. It does seem that the date conversion is happenening ahead of the filter so this is causing the error.

In this use case, switching to the recomended [CONVERT](https://https:/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) function with style 103 as opposed to building it with substring did help.

Note this only helped in this use case of converting from UK format to ISO 8601 and has not in another so I will generate a new question to cover that specific.